# How to handle multiple tapping on toolbar item in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to implement enable/disable  property of toolbar item.

Here is the scenario,
On toolbar item  activation I want to open dialog box.

issue:
When I tapped the toolbar item multiple times then it call multiple times dialog box. Please give some solution to handle the multiple calling of dialog box.

Comment: You could use modal dialogue box, or check if it’s already opened and do nothing, or close/reopen it..

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Here is xml:

<ToolbarItem   Icon="logout_black"  Order="Primary"   Activated="Handle_Activated_1">

Comment: on toolbar activation I'm calling: Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>                 {    var response = await UserDialogs.Instance.ConfirmAsync(new ConfirmConfig     {   Message = "Are you sure you want to logout from this app?",                         Title = "Logout",   OkText = "YES",  CancelText = "NO"    );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the multiple clicks, you can use a variable, to prevent calling the Dialog while waiting for the result confirmation.

first, in your class declare a variable `canTap`;

```
private bool _canTap = true;
```

Assuming your method when tapping the toolbar is like this:

```
private void ItemTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if(_canTap)
     {
       _canTap= false;
      Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => { 
                var response = await 
              UserDialogs.Instance.ConfirmAsync(new ConfirmConfig { Message = "Are you sure you want to logout from this app?", Title = "Logout", OkText = "YES", CancelText = "NO" );
                 if(response)
                 {
                 }
                 else
                 {
                 }
                 _canTap = true;)};
}
```